# Using a Singleton pattern to Linq to Sql Data Context

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, design-patterns, linq-to-sql

I have some confusion in Linq to SQL.I am searching for an actual reason why Data context class gives follwing Exception some times .

"There is already an open data reader associated with this command which must be closed first

Specially in multitasking environment.Most people are saying that the reason is ,Data Context is not thread Safe.All are suggesting to use DataContex as one per unit of work.

Please refer following  thread for best answer

[Linq-to-SQL Data Context across multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918625/linq-to-sql-datacontext-across-multiple-threads)

But in my case,i am using another class call "A" which is implemented in Singleton pattern.Purpose of this class is ,provide Data context object in singleton manner.I am maintaining instance of this class "A" as global instance in derived class and calling to Datacontex by using particular instance.

**My question is,**

Will my method call cause uncontrolled memory growth ? based on my understanding,singleton maintaining one instance as static object .If my assumption is wrong ,please give me good explanation.

**Note:**

Any way my method call also throws same exception.So i am sure same problem is happen in this scenario also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach will cause problems in general. A `DataContext` is not intended to be a singleton. Just don't do it.

Even if `A` is a singleton, create a new `DataContext` within the appropriate methods within `A`, rather than having a `DataContext` as a variable within `A`. (You might also want to consider whether `A` should really be a singleton in the first place.)

Comment: Thanks.Can you explain me little detail ,what kind of problem can occur?

Comment: @Thabo: In a multi-threaded environment, all kinds of things could go wrong - such as the exception you're seeing. Even in a single-threaded environment, you may well end up seeing cached data, as well as memory usage increasing forever. You just need to accept that `DataContext` was not designed to be used like this, and change your design. You shouldn't be weighing up the pros and cons - *just don't do it*.

Comment: .Thanks but i have one doubt also.If i don't use Singleton how concurrency will be handle.?If create new Datacontex objects always,how it will be controlled?Eg what will happen if a Datacontext access a table when another Datacontext access same table(Read of modify)

Comment: @Thabo: It will depend on the exact nature of what they're doing... but you shouldn't be controlling database concurrency in that way anyway. For example, you may well want to have multiple servers, all talking to the same database. LINQ to SQL has various approaches to concurrency, which you should learn about - and they *don't* involve sharing a single `DataContext`.

Comment: Thanks.Can u give a best tutorial or references to understand how to approach concurrency in LINQ to SQL?:)

Comment: @Thabo: Well there are lots of books about LINQ. I suggest you find a well-reviewed one.

Answer (score 2):

I actually came here because I felt a singleton pattern would be perfect for the Linq Datacontext too. But after seeing your issues it makes since why it's not.

Here's an example of how I'd write a Singleton Linq DataContext:

```
class DataAccess
{
    private static DataContext db = null;

    private DataAccess()
    {
    }

    public static DataContext GetInstance()
    {
        return db ?? (db = new DataContext());
    }
}
```

In the singleton pattern you set the DataContext instance as static. Well, in a multi-threaded environment a static object is going to cause collisions like the errors you're seeing. You are lucky to get those errors. Using multiple threads you could submit changes from another thread and then have the original thread submit causing a big mess.

I'd stick to non static implementation. True me I know it's disappointing, I really wanted to use that pattern here too.