# How to load a DataGridView correctly while updated happening

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I implemented a DataGridView some time ago. It works nice. Now I was doing some heavy-load testing, but it failed. It throws exceptions everywhere, at least when it tries to load the data.

**Problem: DataContext Refresh**

There is a method where I refresh the the data inside the `DataGridView`.

*One exception tells me there is already a `DataReader` open, which I have to close first.*

*The second exception tells me "the operation cannot be performed during a call to submitchanges".*

The problem is that I am not working with `DataReaders` myself, I am using the approach you see below:

```
 this.bindingSource.EndEdit();
 this.bindingSource.DataSource = null;

 // DataControl is my controler where the table is stored. It is a singleton.
 DataControl.Instance.m_DBTable.Context.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, DataControl.Instance.m_DBTable);
 this.bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
 this.bindingSource.DataSource = DataControl.Instance.m_DBTable;
```

I hope someone can help me on this one. Feel free to ask for more details if needed.

Thanks

**More exceptions thrown (not only on that method, but on the same form.)**

- Internal connection fatal error
- Sql DateTime-Overflow  (must be between 1/1/1753 and 21/31/9999) (I really do ALWAYS initialize all my date-time variables!)
- Invalid reading operation when there is no data available.
- No reference exception.

Comment: Throws exceptions everywhere - where exactly? At least one example. As I understand you use LinqToSql, don't you? How are you testing the heavy load?

Comment: Basically every time the DataGridView is loading the data. After the initialisation everything works fine and the table gets updated correctly. To test the heavy load I connected the database to the system changing values. There are about 15 new updates on the Database and the DataGridView should show the Table.

Comment: I have very limited experience with LINQ to SQL, so tell me what is the type of m_DbTable? Try to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546190(v=vs.100).aspx. It may contain some useful insights.

Comment: I actually did not write a single codeline of LINQToSQL. I only did the mapping with the System.Data.Linq.Table - Namespace. Then the DataBinding should have done the job for me. Apparently this does not work so well.

Comment: And I still do not understand how use test the heavy load (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing). Do you launch multiple instances of you program or you create multiple instances of your data layer? Is it done manually or automatically. On one machine or from few?

Comment: I am testing how my application behaves on heavy load. I am ignoring the hardware part. Basically there is an other machine retreiving data and updating a database with the new values. Now I am testing the application with this machine working on 100% and the application fails to load the datagrid view.

Comment: Let's try to at least dissect the problem area. Do not bind the data. Just try to dump them into a file or somewhere else.  We will be sure that the problems are not caused by binding.

Comment: Looks like it is a multithread-problem. Because the server is the one who updates the database (after receiving data over TCP/IP).
The datatable is a singleton because it is global. I will try to separate it and make one connection for the datagridview and one for updating the database.

Answer (score 0):

any time you are getting errors relating to this wrap your datareader in a using statement. This goes for any reader / writer

```
using(var daraReader = new DataReader())
{

 // Use your data reader here, it will not be left open

}
```

Comment: As I said, I am not handling DataReaders myself. I am using DataBindings and LinqToSql.

Comment: @AdrianBooth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821574/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-should-datacontext-be-disposed-using-idisposable

Answer (score 0):

DataContext isn't actually designed to be singleton [Using a Singleton pattern to Linq to Sql Data Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221784/using-a-singleton-pattern-to-linq-to-sql-data-context). That's the first thing you should consider in your code.

If it doesn' work - try to at least dissect the problem area(http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Do not bind the data. Just try to dump them into a file or somewhere else. We will be sure that the problems are not caused by binding.

If it won't work also then it is quite possible you are having problems due to concurrency issues in LINQ to SQL and your database. Looks like standard locks and mechanisms does not work as intended. Or they work too diligently.

There are few decent articles http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/05/22/into-to-linq-to-sql-optimistic-concurrency.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38299/How-To-Handle-Concurrency-in-LINQ-to-SQL that explain concurrency in LINQ.

I hope that some of it could help.