# DbContext has been disposed with multiple partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a view that has 3 partial views separated by tabs. Each partial view queries the database and returns results to a list displayed in a table. The data access layer uses a generic repository to access the data.

Here is the generic method that gets all the results for a single table:

```
 public virtual IList<T> GetAll<T>(params Expression <Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties) where T : class
        {

            try
            {
                using (Context)
                {
                    List<T> list;
                    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = Context.Set<T>();

                    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                        dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

                        list = dbQuery.AsNoTracking().ToList();

                    return list;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid state: {typeof(T).Name} DbSet is null.", ex);
            }
        }
```

[Here is the resource I used for creating this method](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

To use this method I manually include the navigation properties. These are the navigation properties used in the view.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> DataTableAsync<TEntity>(AlertModel alert, string viewName = null, 
params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties) where TEntity : class
        {

            // get data
            var data = (from a in await LimsManager.AllAsync<TEntity>(navigationProperties)
                        select a).ToList();

            // create sample log model 
            var response = new TableModel<TEntity>
            {
                Data = data
            };

            return PartialView(viewName ?? $"_{typeof(TEntity).Name}Table", response);

        }
```

The navigation properties are passed in via a lambda expression `s => s.'NavigationProperty'`.

On this view I make a call to the `GetAll()` method for each partial view. The first two partial views return correctly but third partial view always gives me the context has been disposed error. This happens even when calling `.ToList()`.

To my understanding through researching the problem it seems like the context is being disposed at the end of the second call so by the third time it calls [the context is already gone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27710399/2359206).

So my question is, how can I prevent the context from being disposed before the third call?

Comment: Your `Context` instance is disposed whenever it reaches end of the `using` statement. If there is single instance shared between different instances of your generic repositories you are trying to use disposed instance. I bet you get that same error when you call `DataTableAsync` method twice in a row.

Comment: @dropoutcoder That's exactly the issue I discovered a few minutes ago. Check my answer. I had one Context instance being shared for the entire class.

Answer (score 0):

Learning something new every day.

In my Entity Framework library (DAL) I had a context constructor

```
 public Store(EntitiesContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }
```

In my method I was using `Context`. So each time the method was called it was using the Context created when the class was instantiated and being disposed of. To fix it I just placed the context creation directly in the using statement. So instead of `using(Context)` I changed it to `using (var db = new LimsEntitiesContext())`